# call to undefined function session_unregister() when trying output

Tags: php, mysql

monitoring this error when logout.
thank you

```
function doLogout()
{
if(isset($_SESSION['username']));
{
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_unregister('username');
}
header('Location: logme.php');
exit;
}
```

Comment: As of 5.4 [`session_unregister`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php) has been removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. omit `;`
2. from [php.net `session_unregister()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php)

**This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.**

> ```
> function doLogout()
>     {
>     if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
>     {
>     unset($_SESSION['username']);       
>     }
>     header('Location: logme.php');
>     exit;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

`session_unregister` isn't available since php 5.4, so you can remove the function call.

An equal call would be just `unset` - so you can replace

```
session_unregister('username');
```

with

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

if you don't want to rewrite your whole code, you can write your own session_unregister function

```
if (!function_exists('session_unregister')) {
    function session_unregister($var) { unset($_SESSION[$var]); }
}
```

*This function doesn't do the same, but is in most cases sufficient*

Answer (score 3):

According to the PHP manual, `session_unregister()` function has been DEPRECATED ...

[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php)

use `unset($_SESSION["key"]);` instead

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using PHP >= 5.4

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php